# TypeError unsupported operand with Python inputs

Tags: python, string, input, typeerror

I have to create a rental car cost estimator by collecting customer input, calculating the costs from the input, and then displaying the results. The part where I'm stuck on is collecting the odometer readings for the total miles they drove. It's giving me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rental_car.py", line 39, in 
    totalMiles = odoEnd - odoStart
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

I uploaded the code to [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/gEb2UKtx) and was hoping someone could give me some insight on how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like `odoEnd` and `odoStart` are of type `str` so, you can try: `totalMiles = float(odoEnd) - float(odoStart)` .

Comment: It’s probably a good idea to covert the variables to float as soon as they are defined so you don’t need to repeat it and so you don’t forget.

Answer (score -1):

Convert all your inputs into numeric form.

For example, apply `int` or `float` to your input strings:

```
daysRented = int(input("Number of Days Rented:\n"))
weeksRented = int(input("Number of Weeks Rented:"))
odoStart = float(input("Starting Odometer Reading:\n"))
odoEnd = float(input("Ending Odometer Reading:\n"))
```

The default behaviour is noted explicitly in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input):

> **input**([*prompt*])
>
> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output
>   without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input,
>   **converts it to a string** (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.